# Python writing to file keeps memory allocated

Tags: python, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a large program (simulation of a business process) where I use a separate process to write finished parts to a file. The problem is that when writing the data to the file, the program still keeps the data in memory even if I explicitly tell it to delete it. If I run the same program with only the line for writing into file commented, it won't keep any of the data in memory.
Do I do something wrong with freeing the memory?

This is the part of the code responsible for writing it to file:

```
class CSVCustomWriter:
    def __init__(self, simulation_id, csv_delimiter, attribute_names):
        self.csv_delimiter = csv_delimiter
        self.simulation_id = simulation_id
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
        self.header = ['CaseId', 'Activity', 'Start', 'End', 'Resource',
                       'CostPerEvent', 'CostPerResource'] + attribute_names
        self.base_path = os.path.join('results', str(self.simulation_id))
        if not os.path.exists(self.base_path):
            os.makedirs(self.base_path)
        self.path_csv = os.path.join(self.base_path, 'data.csv')
        self.file = open(self.path_csv, 'wt', encoding='utf-8')
        self.file.write(self.csv_delimiter.join(self.header) + '\n')
        self.closed = False

    def add(self, data):
        buffer = ''
        case_id, previous_activities, attributes = data
        current_attributes = tuple(attributes[a] for a in self.attribute_names)
        for a in previous_activities:
            buffer += self.csv_delimiter.join(
                (str(case_id), str(a[0]), str(a[1]), str(a[2]), str(a[6]), str(a[4]), str(a[5]))
                + current_attributes)
            buffer += '\n'

        self.file.write(buffer)
        del current_attributes
        del case_id
        del previous_activities
        del attributes
        del buffer

    def close(self):
        if not self.closed:
            self.file.close()
            self.closed = True
```

After each case ends, its sent using the add method to be written to the file. If I remove self.file.write(buffer) line, the usage of ram for this part of the program drops to nearly zero.

Comment: If you are still interested in this issue, a minimally reproducible example would help.  You could add a few lines to do the needed imports, call the constructor, and call add() a few times.

Comment: It would also help to clarify what your evidence is for your assertion that "the program still keeps the data in memory even if I explicitly tell it to delete it".

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum only partially. I changed process into a thread and it stopped storing it in memory. I still have no idea how I would do it while using a process

Comment: @Ondrej any chance you have any further ideas now? Has this been raised against pysam? We seem to have encountered the same issue :(